# Join video-file m4v and audio file m4a. to make a mp4?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor

What is best way, to join a Video-Only file, .m4v
with m4a audio file, and output as mp4

Want to join them, without losing original quality,
both file have same time length.

any good software.etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i audiofile.m4a -i videofile.m4v  -c copy  combined.mp4
```

Here `-c copy` tells to copy the stream instead of re-encoding. So the streams are as before. It is fastest and lossless.